# Why people of Bengal worship Durga also during Basanti Puja?

Tags: shiva, upanishads, durga, shakti

There is a festival in Bengal region named Basanti Puja in which Bengali people worship Goddess Durga but why they worship Maa Durga in Basanti Puja also,whereas they have time to worship Goddess Durga in Durga Puja? Is there any reason or story behind this?

Comment: Basanti puja is Durga puja only.,the only difference being that instead of the Sharad(autumn) season it is celebrated in the spring.See this link for history and how it originated :https://www.facebook.com/DurgapujaBangladesh/posts/167171333403620

Comment: @Rickross,do you live in Bengal?

Comment: Rohit,......yes i do  :)

Comment: Rickross,I also live in Bengal!

Answer (score 3):

Basanti Puja is also known as Basant Durga Puja.

It is believed that at the time of Yuddha Between Rama and Ravana. Lord Rama was finding difficulty to defeat the king Ravana. Lord Rama needed blessings of Goddess Durga. Because Rama's wife Mata sita was being kidnapped by King Ravana(known as *Sita Haran*). So Lord Rama changed the time of Durga pooja for seeking blessings of Mata Durga.

Also the legends of *Markanda Purana* describes that, King *Surath* has lost his kingdom and was wandering in forests where he met *Samadhi Vaishya* who also lost his kingdom. There they both met *Medha Muni* who suggested them to do Basanti Puja. So they did Basanti Puja and finally got their kingdoms back.

In this way the ritual of Basanti Puja started.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

Basanti Durga Puja is the celebration of Durga Puja during the spring time. It is a huge celebration in the eastern parts of India and especially in West Bengal. Basanti Durga puja coincides with the Vasant or Chaitra Navratri celebrations. If you are confused that why Durga puja is celebrated in the spring time then let us tell you about the origin of the festival.
Scriptures say that originally Durga puja was performed during spring time. However when Lord Ram invoked the Goddess untimely (Akal Bodhan) during autumn or Sharad, people started following the suit. Hence the autumnal or Sharadiya Durga puja became more popular than the original celebration of Basanti Durga puja.Thus,Goddess Durga is worshipped during Basanti Puja

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Answer (score 0):

For the festival of Basanti Puja, it is believed that the King Surath has performed the first ever Durga Puja in the Spring, after getting the instructions from the Sage Mesha. Also, according to the legend in Markanda Puran, it is stated that the king Surath has also lost his kingdom and wandered in the forests. His met Samadhi Vaishya has also lost his kingdom. In the Jungle they both met Medha Muni, who suggested them to perform Basanti Durga Puja for getting back their lost kingdoms. So the Samadhi Vaishya and King Surath performed Basanti Puja and got back their lost kingdoms. So this is that start of ritual of performing Basanti Durga Puja in North Bengal, during the season of Chaitra Month.
Basanti Puja rituals are very similar to Shardiya Durga Puja. But the only difference is in “Ghat” for Bodhan, which is not used in Shashti Puja. This is because this Puja is performed on time when only it is meant to be done.
I hope this post of mine will clear the facts and ritual behind Basanti Puja in North Bengal.